# How to extract the content of SQL-Files using R?

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I have of folder/directory of one of my colleagues full of `sql`statements. The folder is updated by him daily as well. I would like to document these `sql`statements for futures colleagues. However, I'm looking for a way to "automate" that process. 
I thought about to use `crontab` once a week and run a `R-Markdown` file which automatically update the existing `R-Markdown` file.

My approach is as follows:

```
path = "c:/SQL_files/"
out.file<-""
file.names <- dir(path, pattern =".sql") # here I changed `.txt` to `.sql`
for(i in 1:length(file.names)){
file <- read.csv2.sql(file.names[i],header=TRUE, sep=";",    stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  out.file <- rbind(out.file, file)
}


# That second approach comes very close, but just generates a `.txt` for the first
#`.sql` file in the directory with the error:

   Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) : 
   names do not match previous names
```

where the files are:

```
 [1] "c:/SQL_files/first.sql"                                            
 [2] "c:/SQL_files/second.sql"     

 path = "c:/SQL_files/"
 out.file<-""
files <- list.files(path=path, pattern="*.sql", full.names=T, recursive=FALSE)
for(i in 1:length(files)){
  file <- read.table(files[i],header=TRUE, sep=";", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  out.file <- rbind(out.file, file)
}
```

The `loop` which extracts the content of the `.sql` doesnt seem to capture the content at all(in the first example) or captures just the content of the first file in the directory (second example). So my question. Is there a way to extract content from a `SQL Text File (.sql)`? Which may result in the  `.txt/.Rmd` as follows: (but doesnt have to):

output of the first loop:     `my_sql_statement.sql`

output of the second loop:    `Select * From Data`

Comment: So you just want to take all the queries from various files and put thein in one .txt?

Comment: Hi @JakubKania Yes, exactly.Preferably .Rmd,but that just an ideal

Comment: And you are sure you don't want to use version control system instead?

Comment: Yes that would be great to have the upper command running. But thank you for your suggestion!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This RMD file generates a markdown/HTML document listing some meta data and the content of all files specified:

````
---
title: "Collection of SQL files"
author: "SQLCollectR"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%Y-%m-%d')`"
output: 
  html_document: 
    keep_md: yes
---

```{r setup, echo = FALSE}
library(knitr)
path <- "files/"
extension <- "sql"
```

This document contains the code from all files with extension ``r extension`` in ``r paste0(getwd(), "/", path)``.

```{r, results = "asis", echo = FALSE}
fileNames <- list.files(path, pattern = sprintf(".*%s$", extension))
fileInfos <- file.info(paste0(path, fileNames))

for (fileName in fileNames) {
  filePath <- paste0(path, fileName)
  cat(sprintf("## File `%s` \n\n### Meta data \n\n", fileName))
  cat(sprintf(
    "| size (KB) | mode | modified |\n|---|---|---|\n %s | %s | %s\n\n", 
    round(fileInfos[filePath, "size"]/1024, 2), 
    fileInfos[filePath, "mode"],
    fileInfos[filePath, "mtime"]))
  cat(sprintf("### Content\n\n```\n%s\n```\n\n", paste(readLines(filePath), collapse = "\n")))
}

```
````

All the work is done in the `for` loop which iterates over all files in `path` whose names end in `extension`. For each file, a table with "meta data" is printed, followed by the actual file content. The meta data is retrieved using `file.info` and consists of file size, mode and last modified timestamp.

The `cat(sprintf(...` constructs containing markdown make the code look complicated, but it fact it is fairly simple.

### Sample output

Using SQL files with SQL statements from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38578/2706569), the RMD file above generates the following output (using HTML as output format):

[image: Sample output]

Comment: Thats amazing! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

In order to read content from a text file that does not represent a delimited table, you might need to use `readLines` instead of `read.table`.  The `R` way of doing this would use `lapply`:

```
files <- list.files(path=path, pattern="*.sql", full.names=T, recursive=FALSE)
out.files <- lapply(files,readLines)
```

This will give you a list containing a vector of characters (each element is one line of the file).

EDIT:

To answer the rest of your question, this sort of data could be converted into a single text file using `writeLines`.

```
names(out.files)<-files
printer = file("out.sql","w");
lapply(files,function (x) 
{
   writeLines(x,printer);
   writeLines(out.files[[x]],printer);
})
close(printer)
```

I would only do all this if you are doing some other manipulation in R, otherwise there are easier ways to append a bunch of files into one file.

Comment: Hi Thank you. But is there a way to separate/include the file name itself into the produced .txt. Without that its just .txt with just .sql statements

Comment: If the names have not been attached to out.files, you can use names(out.files)<-files.  Is this sufficient for you to create your output file?

Comment: The output looks very unstructured. I'm using `write.list {erer}`.

Comment: @HiThere Perhaps you should try `writeLines` as in the answer instead of `write.list {erer}`.